# Aonde esta pergunta é ampla demais?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, perguntas-fechadas

Nessa pergunta [Para que servem os atributos data-target e data-toggle?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227604/66203), é questionado:

> Preciso saber, para que servem esses dois atributos (**data-target e data-toggle**) que ficam em *input*s, *button*s e semelhantes no HTML?

Até o momento, ela está como fechada por ser ampla demais:

> Fechada como ampla demais por [...] 20/08 às 21:29
>
> Limite a pergunta a um problema específico, e forneça detalhes suficientes para conseguir uma resposta adequada. Evite fazer várias perguntas ao mesmo tempo. Para ajuda sobre como esclarecer a pergunta, veja Como Perguntar
> Conheça as regras na central de ajuda e edite a pergunta para que fique adequada.

Entretanto, não consigo entender, nem ver, onde ela é ampla demais. Para mim, o AP simplesmente quer saber o que são e para que servem os ***data-target e data-toggle*** que se utiliza tanto.

Não estou querendo apontar erros de ninguém, é que eu só quero ter certeza se esse fechamento é apropriado.

Ela realmente é ampla demais? Ou foi fechada com embasamento nas [primeiras versões da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/227604/revisions)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Acho que até cabe um debate, mas pra mim está muito clara na versão atual que não é ampla e reabri.

Mesmo as primeiras versões dava para responder, apesar da falta de cuidado para elaborar a pergunta.